# Problem using curly brackets in functions

Tags: python, function, curly-braces

The line `answer = int(input("What is {number1} * {number2} ?"))` works fine when using without the function, but when I put it in functions, it throws the error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\hjg\Downloads\test4.py", line 17, in <module> answer = eval(input("What is", number1, "*", number2, "?")) NameError: name 'number1' is not defined >>>`.

```py
import random, math

def quiz(answer):
    number1 = random.randint(0,9)
    number2 = random.randint(0,9)


    if answer == correctanswer:
        return print("Correct")
    else:
       return print("Incorrect.")


answer = int(input("What is {number1} * {number2} ?"))
correctanswer = number1 * number2


quiz(number1, number2)
```

Comment: your `number1` and `number2` is defined in your function which is it's scope.

Comment: Your error doesn't match the code

Comment: also, your function takes only 1 argument, not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the variable on top to make it global.

```py
import random, math
number1 = random.randint(0,9)
number2 = random.randint(0,9)

def quiz(answer):
    correctanswer = number1 * number2
    if answer == correctanswer:
        return print("Correct")
    else:
       return print("Incorrect.")

answer = int(input(f"What is {number1} * {number2} ?"))
quiz(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You got little confused on your code.
number1 and number2 should be out of the function and the function need to get only 1 argument.
Try this:

```
      import random

      def quiz(answer: int):
      correctanswer = number1 * number2
      if answer == correctanswer:
        return print("Correct")
      else:
        return print("Incorrect.")

      number1 = random.randint(0,9)
      number2 = random.randint(0,9)
      answer = int(input(f"What is {number1} * {number2} ?"))
      quiz(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `number1` and `number2` inside the function, you'll only be able to access them inside the function. You can either modify the quiz function so that you take the input inside it, or you can initialize the variables outside of the function.

Your function also takes only a single argument, but you pass two. You also don't need to import `math`. Basic arithmetic (add, subtract, multiply, divide, etc.) is built into Python's core, and you only need the `math` package to do more complex things like trigonometry or messing around with Pi.

For example:

```py
import random

def quiz(question, correctanswer):
    answer = int(input(question))
    if answer == correctanswer:
        return print("Correct")
    else:
       return print("Incorrect.")

number1 = random.randint(0, 9)
number2 = random.randint(0, 9)

quiz(f"What is {number1} * {number2} ?", number1 * number2)
```

I suggest you read up on [scoping](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

Answer (score -1):

Its because of your scope. number1 and number2 don't exist where your referencing them.

Comment: number1 = random.randint(0,9)
    number2 = random.randint(0,9)   Those are references.  This works fine without functions.  Also, how do I add lines in these comments?

Comment: that's inside the function. It doesn't exist globally

Comment: This is the local variable thing. How do I change it to a global?  Or how do I make it work?

Comment: The person above shows you. @vkv-onfire

Comment: The actual error   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hjg\Downloads\test4.py", line 14, in <module>
    answer = int(input(f"What is {number1} * {number2} ?"))
NameError: name 'number1' is not defined

Comment: Because it is not defined. you should be reading about functions and basics such as scope, that is beyond this thread.